# Form submission before getting stripe token on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, html, forms, stripe-payments

So my subscription form submits perfectly fine from my laptop/desktop browser, but when I try to submit it from a mobile browser it doesn't work and I go to the else statement in the python code block. I've tried using event.preventDefault();, event.stopPropagation();, event.stopImmediatePropagation();, and return false but nothing seems to result in the desired behavior. I think it's an issue with the stripe_token but I'm not sure. Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong here?

FORM HTML:

```html
<form data-ajax="false" method="POST" action="{{request.path}}" id="subForm">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="form-group ">
                 <div class="alert alert-{% if message.tags == 'error' %}danger{% else %}{{ message.tags }}{% endif %}">
                    <strong> {{ message|safe }} </strong>
                 </div>
              </div>
          {% endfor %}
          <div class="form-group" id="startAddPhone">
              <label>Email</label><br/>
              <input name="email" type="text" required placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="startAddPhone">
              <label>Card Number</label><br/>
              <input name="card_number" type="tel" autocomplete="cc-number" required placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="startAddPhone">
              <label>CVC</label><br/>
              <input name="cvc" type="tel" required placeholder="••••" autocomplete="cc-exp">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="startAddPhone">
              <label>Expiry</label><br/>
              <input name="cc-expired" type="text" required placeholder="MM/YY">
          </div>
           
      </form>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="getStartedBtn" form="subForm">Submit</button>
```

FORM JS:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            var $form = $('form');

            if (response.error) { // Problem!
                // Show the errors on the form
                alert(response.error.message);
                return false;
            } else { // Token was created!

                // Get the token ID:
                var token = response.id;

                // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
                $form.submit()
            }
        }


        Stripe.setPublishableKey('{{token}}');
        $('input[name="card_number"]').payment('formatCardNumber');
        $('input[name="cvc"').payment('formatCardCVC');
        $('input[name="cc-expired"').payment('formatCardExpiry');

        $(document).on('click tap', '#getStartedBtn', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            var expiry = $('input[name="cc-expired"').val().replace(" ", "").replace('/', ' ');
            Stripe.card.createToken({
               number: $('input[name="card_number"]').val(),
               cvc: $('input[name="cvc"').val(),
               exp: expiry
            }, stripeResponseHandler)
        });

        $('form').submit(function(event){
            var stripeToken = $('input[name="stripeToken"]').val();
            if (!stripeToken){
                alert('Invalid Payment details');
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

FORM Python:

```
def subscription(request, unique_code):
user = get_object_or_404(User, access_url=unique_code)

if request.POST:
    stripe_token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
    email = request.POST.get('email')

    if all([stripe_token, email]):
        try:

            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=user).first()
            if customer:
                if subscriptions.has_active_subscription(customer):
                    messages.error(
                        request, 'You already have active subscription')

                    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

            # Create stripe customers
            setattr(user, 'email', email)
            customers.create(
                user=user,
                card=stripe_token,
                charge_immediately=False
            )

            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=user).first()
            subscription = Subscription.objects.filter(
                customer=customer).first()

            stripe_subscription = subscriptions.retrieve(
                customer, subscription.stripe_id)

            subscriptions.sync_subscription_from_stripe_data(
                customer, stripe_subscription)

            # Set default timer
            user_timezone = user.school.timezone
            if not user_timezone:
                user_timezone = 'UTC'

            current_time = timezone.now().astimezone(pytz.timezone(user_timezone))
            expired_at = '9:00 AM'
            if current_time.hour < 22 and current_time.hour > 9:
                expired_at = current_time + timedelta(hours=2)
                expired_at = datetime.strftime(expired_at, '%-I:%M %p')

            timer = Timer.objects.create(user=user, expired_at=expired_at)

            protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'

            access_url = protocol + request.get_host() + \
                reverse('badger_snooze', args=[user.access_url])

            message = client.messages.create(body="Check your LMS! {}".format(
                access_url), to=user.username, from_=settings.TWILIO_NUMBER)

            user.is_active = True
            user.save()

            if request.session.get('user'):
                del request.session['user']

            messages.success(request, 'Thanks for signing up for Badger!')
            return redirect(reverse('badger_finished'))

        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(request, 'You already processed subscription')

        except Exception, err:
            messages.error(request, err)

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'PLEASE PROVIDE PAYMENT DETAILS')

return render(request, 'subscription.html', {'token': settings.PINAX_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY})
```

Comment: "It doesnt work" is almost never useful information.  Giving some specific information on the exact error message or behavior you're seeing when you try to execute the code, particularly when you post large code blocks like these are going to be really helpful for helping get us started on helping you out!

Comment: @DaOgre I've added the actual python code to code above block. When I submit the form from a mobile browser I'm getting the "PLEASE PROVIDE PAYMENT DETAILS" message which happens when the email or stripe token is not sent. So I believe the form is being submitted before I get the stripe token when the form is submitted from a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason you're having this problem is because your 
submit button isnt inside your form element.  As a result on iOS I believe it's submitting without the event handler you want firing due to how the "go" button functions (I could be wrong here).

First, I'd add the submit button into the form element.
Second, since you're not actually interested in this logic happening on button click, I'd move it instead into an onSubmit event for the form, rather than the button, this will ensure that someone can't get around the click as part of the form submission.
Thirdly, it might be worthwhile to add the stripe_token and email to the python response to verify it's not a python problem but I'd guess this is a JS issue